# How can I avoid python converting big numbers to scientific notation?

Tags: python, csv

I have data structured as follows:

```
['1404407396000',
 '484745869385011200',
 '0',
 '1922149633',
 "The nurse from the university said I couldn't go if I don't get another measles immunization...",
 '-117.14384195',
 '32.8110777']
```

I want to write this data to a csv file, but when I do, python converts the numbers to scientific notation (e.g 1.404E12).

I am using the following function to convert the list of lists to a csv:

```
def list_to_csv(data,name_of_csv_string):

    import csv

    """ 
    This function takes the list of lists created from the twitter data and 
    writes it to a csv.

    data - List of lists
    name_of_csv_string  -  What do you think this could be?

    """

    with open(name_of_csv_string + ".csv", "wb") as f:
        writer=csv.writer(f)      
        writer.writerows(data)
```

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Please include a complete, runnable example. It isn't at all clear how your data relates to your `list_to_csv` function, nor what makes you think that Python converts your numbers to scientific notation. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: As you can see from [this program](http://ideone.com/EofowI), Python doesn't convert the numbers to scientific notation. Please describe what you are observing that lead you to conclude that it does.

Comment: @Robᵩ Python does convert to scientific notation. You used Integers in your example in order to be able to observe this effect you need to use floats with a certain amount of decimal places https://ideone.com/qDt3PJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the format specification mini language described here:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

Search for:  7.1.3.1. Format Specification Mini-Language

Answer (score 0):

Use string formatting.

```
writer.writerows("%f" % data)
```

There are various formatting options you can check out [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was the Microsoft Excel app which was converting the numbers to scientific notation (even in the formula bar the numbers were in scientific notation).

**Try opening the csv file using Notepad or a standard text editor** to make sure if the numbers are saved as integers. In my case, the Notepad showed normal integer numbers, while it was Excel which showed them in the Scientific Notation form.